# The Twitter case taking into account the future of remote work. Can labour policies put a limit?

Tags: labor-policies

One of the first actions taken by Elon Musk after taking over Twitter was the [ban on remote work](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-63582273). This is nothing new. Marissa Meier [did the same](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2013/feb/25/yahoo-chief-bans-working-home) shortly after becoming the new CEO of Yahoo. The reason is quite simple. Many US workers have to endure long commutes. Housing close to most workplaces is often scarce and expensive. The sudden switch will push some to leave their jobs and usually the first ones to give up are older workers with a family. This is a common trick to get rid of the less flexible workers without appearing to discriminate anyone. Actually these tricks are often used also in Europe, struggling companies may move their offices from one city to another, employees of consulting companies or temporary agencies may be told: *"from the next Monday you'll work onsite for the new client 100 Kilometres from here"*.

But still there is a limit to this kind of actions. The employment contracts have a working location and the companies cannot move working location in a far region without offering a relocation package or at least some time to organise the transfer. In the Twitter case [Musk had to go even further](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-63648505) to the point that he drew the attention of the unions.

What is going to happen if remote work keeps expanding? Many workers in recent times have been offered a contract with a working location more than 100 Km from home with the promise of remote work. Those workers are a lot more vulnerable if their employers decide to take similar actions. The existing limitation can be easily circumvented, the employer could tell the employee that they have to work hundreds of kilometres from home with little notice. This is because the labour legislation in many countries does not take into account that modern arrangements could be based on a virtual working location completely disconnected from the physical location where the worker lives. Can this be fixed? Is there the will and the way to restore the current situation?

**Note:**
@SJuan76 claimed in a comment that the problem does not exist, because a verbal promise of a work from home arrangement is legally binding, but in the Twitter case a [promise repeated also on the media](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-52628119) was easily broken. Furthermore the trick of suddenly terminating work from home is likely to be used more often in Europe where firing employees is a lot more difficult and in Europe matters what is written in the contract.

BTW I understand that there might be different answers depending on the area, if answers can be tagged with the applicable countries like it happens in the law forum, it would be welcome.

Comment: I think this is a fairly important question in evolving labor policy in a field that essentially didn't exist 15 years ago, *whether or not you agree* that extra regulations are needed.  Please don't DV willy-nilly just because you disagree.  And there are probably white papers and research stuff that has looked at this subject already.

Comment: It would be interesting to look at the Working Hours Adjustment Act of the Netherlands (De Wet aanpassing arbeidsduur). [Since 2015](https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/stb-2015-245.html) workers have the right to ask their employers about changing their place of work, including working from home. The employer has no obligation to consent, but must discuss his decision with the employee. I suspect a corresponding rule about the right of employers to ask their employees to change the working place does not exist, although that is beyond my ability to research legal discussions in Dutch.

Comment: "This is a common trick to get rid of the less flexible workers without appearing to discriminate anyone"? No, it is an overt trick meant to discriminate against poor inflexible workers. Do you want to do inflexible work??

Comment: VtC because it is opinion-based. That said, judges usually have the power to decide that a given policy is a way to unfairly discriminate against a population. To do it, they usually factor in lots of aspects: for example its objectives, if the measures are reasonably linked to its objectives, the impact on the population. A policy firing everybody whose name is not of European origin could easily be struck as racist, but Twitter chosing to force on-premises work will usuably be seen as related to a purely business decision (if it is a good or a bad decision is not up to the judge to decide)

Comment: Re "New contracts offered together with the verbal promise" is a non sequitur. The promise is binding even if it is verbal. But work contracts are renegotiated all the time (including salaries). Even in worker-friendly EU, the business can almost always invoke business needs to force a change of conditions. What laws offer are that if the employee does not want to agree, he is fired and gets some severance pay and social benefits (instead of being as he had voluntarily left the job). Of course, all of this moot in countries where firing employees is free.

Comment: @SJuan76 *"Even in worker-friendly EU, the business can almost always invoke business needs to force a change of conditions. What laws offer are that if the employee does not want to agree, he is fired and gets some severance pay"* That is not true. In Europe if the employer decides to change the contract and the worker refuses the change the employer cannot fire the worker. If you where referring to a location change it usually happens that the employer declares a state of economic difficulty and closes the office in one city moving people to another, but it is a special situation.

Comment: Verbal promises of work from home might be binding but it is also legal in many states in the US for an employer to terminate someone's employment for any reason including not wanting to stop working remotely and move to the office. Unless there are laws in place limiting why an employee can be fired there is nothing legally wrong with giving an ultimatum to work in the office or be fired regardless of what existing contracts they have.

Comment: "working contracts" - Not in the US.

Comment: @paulj Corrected

Comment: What exactly is the question? It's obvious that either legislation could be introduced (e.g. allowing the right to work from home where reasonable), or it could be included in employment contracts (whether individual or the result of union bargaining). But it's not clear if governments will legislate, or what the tendency will be for private contracts (I'd guess if in-demand workers want it it may be). Beyond that, what do you want to know? And how does this relate to politics?

Comment: Wasn't remote work predominantly a measure to prevent spread of C19 which was treated by managers with mixed feelings as they had problems to supervise their workers? Then issue is solved, and last people who are worried should get their second booster. In bigger picture I don't think Big Tech employees from California should say aloud that their work can be done well remotely, as if that's the truth one should replace them with someone much cheaper from Asia or Eastern Europe.

Comment: If you want to improve the question, you could ask what legislation has been proposed to enshrine the rights to remote working. Or maybe something about whether data, research, and current trends indicate an interest for remote working either from workers or employers, although even that risks being a bit vague.

Comment: @Shadow1024 For some companies that might be true but for others they use it as a perk to draw in talent that they would not otherwise get. If a company does the work to set up remote work it is possible that they could draw in top talent from around the globe that they would not be able to otherwise if they required people to work in the office.

Comment: @StuartF *"What exactly is the question?"* A possible answer is one tagged by country saying whether the local government is turning a blind eye on the issue. Or whether some legislation in a country might recognise the existence of a virtual working location disconnected from the place of residence of the worker. In such case a shift from the residence location to the ex-virtual location might be considered a relocation.

Comment: It all depends on what is written in the work contract. Often governments impose limits of what can be written into such contracts. A verbal promise may not be legally binding. If in doubt, consult a lawyer. What else can one say?

Comment: @Trilarion "Often governments impose limit" that limit is there now, but from now on it can be circumvented. This is what my question is about. Delegating even more to the individual contract means weakening the worker position.

Answer (score -5):

There should be no governmental policies about where a business should be allowed to say that it's employees should work from. In the case of remote versus office work there are many legitimate reasons that a business could chose to allow or not allow someone to work remotely either in the same area or in another part of the country/world. These decisions have large impacts on the business and costs of doing business in general. There are different costs involved with having employees work in the office and work remotely no matter where that may be.

Examples of the extra costs are for setting up the infrastructure to allow them to access the company network and hardware remotely which isn't free and can be expensive to set up and maintain. There is also the added costs of getting remote employees the needed hardware, keeping it up to date and retrieving it when they leave. While it may sound simple to just say work remotely there are costs and processes that need to be done that don't have to happen if they are working in the office.

This is something that should be dealt with by the employees with use of organizations such as a union to put pressure on the business to allow them to do things such as remote work.

While there are things that the government can and does do to help employees such as setting a work week and hours as well as a minimum wage they should not go overboard with setting rules.

If you are talking about an existing contract there is nothing stopping a business from terminating an employment contract or asking an employee for a change in that contract as needed. All contract violations should be handled by the employees in question and the court system and not something for a government to interfere with.

Comment: Off Topic. The question did not talk about imposing a working location, this question is about the risk of sudden changes in the working locations.

Comment: I can also explain it in a different manner. The working location currently is specified in the contract, it is part of the legal agreement between the worker and the employer. If the employer want to change the working location they have to change their contract. If future contracts specify only the virtual location, but the promise of remote work is only verbal (which is quite common) now the employer has the possibility to make a drastic change in the agreement with the worker that is not a change in the contract, invisible from the legal point of view.

Comment: @FluidCode Anything in the contract that isn't being honored is up to the employees to enforce via the court system. It isn't the responsibility of a government to ensure that a business is following every part of their contracts with employees. Besides they still have the option of terminating the contract as they see fit.

Comment: You make a lot of statements but give no reasons why you believe them to be the case, the addition of which I think would improve the answer.  By the standards of contracts employment contracts are pretty heavily regulated, so some people obvious think it is a good use of government regulatory effort.

Comment: @User65535 It is not the governments job to enforce contracts rather it is the employees, employers, and the courts job to do that. The government has no say and shouldn't have any say in deciding if an employer allows their employees to work remotely in any form or not.

Comment: I get that you think that, but I am saying that the answer would be improved by adding reasons, particularly wrt the other factors of employment contracts that are regulated.